# Combining a passport openID-stategy with JWT

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js, jwt

I've run into a problem when trying to authenticate with passport.js using openID ([passport-steam](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-steam/)), and then using tokens (JWT) instead of sessions.

My current code looks like this:

```
app.post('/auth/steam', passport.authenticate('steam'));

app.get('/auth/steam/return',
  passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/', session: false }),
  function(req, res) {
    var token = jwt.encode({ useridentifier: req.user.identifier}, tokenSecret);

    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

However, the problem I'm having is: How should I communicate the token back to the client? Since it is a GET request that is run after coming back from Steam's site, I can't reply with a simple

```
res.json(token)
```

like I've seen people using local strategies together with JWT do.

The only solution I've managed to come up with involves using a session (e.g. connect-flash) containing the token and communicating it through a REST API to the client after he's been redirected to '/', but the whole point of using JWT is to avoid using sessions, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many days of thinking without getting anywhere I managed to figure out another way to solve it, using cookies.

I found out about the custom callback that passport provides, where I can set the response's headers, so I set one like this before redirecting:

```
res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true });
```

(no secure yet, because I'm only testing on a local server)

This is what the whole code looks like now:

```
app.get('/auth/steam', passport.authenticate('steam'));

app.get('/auth/steam/return', 
  function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('steam', function(err, user, info){ 
      var payload = {
        user: user.identifier
      };

      var token = jwt.sign(payload, "thisisnotthesecretiactuallyuse", {expiresIn : 60*60*24});
      res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true /* TODO: Set secure: true */ }); 

      res.redirect('/'); 
    })(req, res, next)
  });
```